# How to get the caller's class name inside a function without passing it as a parameter?

Tags: c++

**Goal:**
To get the caller's class name inside a function, without passing
the caller's information as parameter to the function.

**Problem:**
I have searched online for days, and I have not found a proper way to get the class name inside a function without passing the caller's information (such as class instance, class name as string, etc.) as a parameter.

**Example:**

**// A.h**

```
// This is Macro Function
#define Print_Data_Macro_Function()
    Print_Data_Template()

template<typename T>
void Print_Data_Template()
{
   // ... do some stuff 
 
   std::cout << "The class that calls Print_Data_Macro_Function() is " << **[Caller's Class Name]** << "\n";
}
```

**//  B.cpp**

```
#include "A.h"

void B::do_something()
{
   Print_Data_Macro_Function();
}
```

**// Main.cpp**

```
#include "B.h"

int main()
{
   B b_object;

   b_object.do_something();

   return 0;
}
```

**// Output I want:**

The class that calls Print_Data_Macro_Function() is B

Comment: In C++, there isn't any way to get the Caller's Class Name inside a function

Comment: Also, `Print_Data_Macro_Function();` won't compile; the template parameter `T` is neither explicitly specified, nor can be deduced from arguments (as the function doesn't take any).

Comment: It might be helpful to understand *why* you want this.

Comment: Maybe `std::source_location` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location) in **C++ 20** is what yout want.

Comment: IMHO, what you want is useless. Because when you write your code, you definitely know who is calling `Print_Data_Macro_Function()`. So if you need to do something with this information inside of the callee, just pass the information into the callee using a parameter.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik Thank you for your response. As long as you know my intention that works for all. I just want to know if there are any ways to do it. I found a possible approach before: #include <source_location>, but I just realized that I cannot used C++20 Standard Library, so I cannot use this API.

Comment: @Dave Newton
I am working on a program that already contained the similar code as my example of this post, and right now I need to print out the caller's class name without touching Print_Data_Macro_Function()'s parameter format, as too many places are calling Print_Data_Macro_Function().

Comment: @Phil1970
Yes, I found this approach before, but I found out my program does not support C++20, so this approach will not work.

Comment: @ZZL If so, boost runtime trace may help you.

Comment: Yves Yes, I will know what you mean. If I can do this way, then I will not consider asking this question. Since too many places are calling Print_Data_Macro_Function(), it is my job to keeping Print_Data_Macro_Function() as it is, while being able to print out the Caller's class name.

Comment: @Yves
May I ask if you have the reference link for your suggestion please?

Comment: @ZZL I just know there is a stuff called boost backtrace: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/stacktrace/getting_started.html, but I've never used it before. Maybe you could start from this link.

Comment: I've rolled back both your updates. The first one is unnecessary: you're right that the description of the problem is clear, and you don't need to justify *why* you want to do this. The second update invalidates an existing answer (mine), so it's not an edit you should make. There's no harm in having a C++20 solution here anyway, even if it doesn't help you directly. You can still get other answers to this question, and more importantly, future readers might well be able to use C++20, and the answer would be useful to them.

Comment: @cigien Thank you for specifying the rules of using stackoverflow. I am a new guy here, and I hope my pose actually helps people and myself to prevent confusions.

Answer (score 1):

From C++20, you can use [std::source_location](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location), which gives the name of the calling function via [function_name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location/function_name), which includes the name of the class to which the function belongs.

```
void Print_Data_Template(const std::source_location location = 
                         std::source_location::current())
{
    std::cout << location.function_name() << '\n';
}
```

which prints

```
void B::do_something()
```

for your example snippet. [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8qoGaW9bv).

You could do some additional string parsing to get just the name of the class, though I think the exact format of the returned string is not specified.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. This was a good approach, if I am allowed to use C++20 standard library. Sorry about the confusion.